# Is rails config "Central Time (US & Canada)" same as "/usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Eastern" for local time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, timezone

I want to configure same time zone rails and it's environment.

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Eastern /etc/localtime
```

And for rails in `application.rb` I added `config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'`.

But I'm not sure these two time zone are same. Is there no difference between them like summer time? Is there something I should concern about?

Comment: Eastern and Central time are 2 different timezones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Eastern time zone is one hour ahead of Central.  You may find some errors occur if you treat them as the same thing in your code.